# Royal Flush not working for Card Hand Assignment [C]

Tags: c, playing-cards

I have tried everything! I'm supposed to add on the Royal Flush part. I understand the straight, flush, and straight flush part, but I cannot seem to get the Royal Flush part. In the end, the code is supposed to print how many straight, flushes, straight flushes, and royal flushes were in the deck of 50000 cards. This started out as a lab that I had with a partner, but now for extra credit, I'm supposed to add on the royal flush part and I'm clueless. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 50000

typedef struct card_t_struct{
    int value; // 1 through 13
    int suit; // 0 is clubes, 1 is diamonds, 2 is spades, 3 is hearts
} card_t;

void printCard(card_t card){
    if(card.value == 1){
        printf("Ace");
    }else if(card.value == 11){
        printf("Jack");
    }else if(card.value == 12){
        printf("Queen");
    }else if(card.value == 13){
        printf("King");
    }else{
        printf("%d", card.value);
    }

    printf(" of ");

    if(card.suit == 0){
        printf("Clubs.");
    }else if(card.suit == 1){
        printf("Diamonds.");
    }else if(card.suit == 2){
        printf("Spades.");
    }else if(card.suit == 3){
        printf("Hearts.");
    }else{
        printf("%d not a suit", card.suit); // Error message
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void hand(card_t* a){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printCard(a[i]);
    }
}

void shuffle(card_t* array, int length){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < length * 2; i++){
        int from = rand() % length;
        int to = rand() % length;
        card_t temp = array[from];
        array[from] = array[to];
        array[to] = temp;
    }
}

void bubble(card_t* f, int length){
    int i = 0;
    int bub_num = 0;
    for(bub_num = 0; bub_num < length; bub_num++){
        for(i = 0; i < length - 1; i++){
            if(f[i].value > f[i+1].value){ // Wrong order
                int temp = f[i].value;
                f[i].value = f[i+1].value;
                f[i+1].value = temp;
            }else{

            }
        }
    }
}

int isFlush(card_t* deck){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        if(deck[i].suit != deck[0].suit){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int isStraight(card_t* deck){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        if(deck[i+1].value != deck[i].value + 1){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int isSFlush(card_t* deck){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        if(deck[i+1].value != deck[i].value + 1){
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        if(deck[i].suit != deck[0].suit){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int isRFlush(card_t* deck){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        if(deck[i].value != deck[i].value){
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        if(deck[i].suit != deck[0].suit){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    card_t deck[52] = {};
    int i = 0;
    int flush = 0;
    int straight = 0;
    int straight_flush = 0;
    int royal_flush = 0;

    int suit = 0;
    for(suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++){
        int value = 1;
        for(value = 1; value <= 13; value++){
            deck[i].suit = suit;
            deck[i].value = value;
            i++;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        shuffle(deck, 52);
        hand(deck);
        if(isFlush(deck) ){
            flush++;
        }
        printf("\n");

        bubble(deck, 5);
        if(isStraight(deck) ){
            straight++;
        }

        if(isSFlush(deck) ){
            straight_flush++;
        }

        if(isRFlush(deck) ){
            royal_flush++;
        }
    }

    printf("The number of flushes you have is: %d\n", flush);
    printf("The number of straights you have is: %d\n", straight);
    printf("The number of straight flushes you have is: %d\n", straight_flush);
    printf("The number of royal flushes you have is: %d\n", royal_flush);
}
```

Comment: *I have tried everything!* - including debugger?

Comment: `if(deck[i].value != deck[i].value)` what is this supposed to do?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Including debugger. I think there is something genuinely wrong with my coding. After the int main() at the bottom, everything is correct. It is before that.

Comment: @TormundGiantsbane `if(deck[i].value != deck[i].value)` is supposed to pick out what cards would represent a Royal Flush

Comment: @Lauryn you are just comparing a card against itself there.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I figured. So how would I basically get the cards to not compare against itself?

Comment: Aside: you will have problems in other functions too because of `deck[i+1].value` breaking the array bounds.

Comment: @Lauryn It depends on what you actually want to compare it against and what kind of comparison.  You'll have to figure out what exactly you want to be checking.

Comment: Also, why are you ignoring the `0` index with loops like `for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)` ?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I want to compare it against the actual deck. And I want to check the deck for a hand that is a royal flush (A Q, K, J, Ace, and 10 of the same suit)

Comment: @WeatherVane Honestly, my professor started the code so blame him tbh lmao.

Comment: @Lauryn I am not going to write your algorithm for you.  You need to figure out what comparisons need to be made to sufficiently satisfy the criteria for a Royal Flush and then if you have difficulty implementing it in code we can be of assistance.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: @WeatherVane - The index is starting at 1 (not zero) because comparisons are being made against the first card. The `i+1` out-of-bounds issue is still a problem, assuming the `IsXxxx()` functions are being called with a five-card hand.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the existing `IsStraight(...)` function, I'm assuming that your `isRFlush(...)` functions are being passed a five-card hand (not an entire deck) whose cards are in ascending order?

```
int isRFlush(card_t* deck) {

    int i = 0; // zero-based index into your hand of five cards (0-4)

    // This next bit DOESN'T ACTUALLY DO ANYTHING. The reason is that comparing anything
    // with itself will always result in an equality (i.e. 1==1, 3.14==3.14, a==a, etc),
    // so this comparison always returns false, and the return 0 after the if statement
    // is never taken, regardless of the value of the cards passed in.
    /*
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (deck[i].value != deck[i].value) { // <--- Never false, no matter what
            return 0;
        }
    }
    */

    // What the other isXxxx methods above were doing was ensuring that each 'next' card
    // was 'one higher' than the card that came before it in the hand. If that's found to
    // be untrue for any card in the hand, then the function exits with a zero.
    //
    // That's the logic for a STRAIGHT, but we're looking for a ROYAL STRAIGHT, so the
    // hand HAS to be "10 J Q K A" (all of the same suit, but we'll check that part later).
    //
    // Since the Ace represents a non-sequential value, I think you may as well just do
    // this using five comparisons without the loop:
    if (   deck[0].value != 1       // if 1st card isn't Ace
        || deck[1].value != 10      // or 2nd card isn't 10
        || deck[2].value != 11      // or 3rd card isn't Jack
        || deck[3].value != 12      // or 4th card isn't Queen
        || deck[4].value != 13) {   // or 5th card isn't King

        return 0; // Not a royal straight
    }

    // If we've made it this far, we know that we have a ROYAL STRAIGHT (e.g. 10, J, Q, K, A)

    // Now, we need to ensure that we also have a FLUSH

    // Loop through the 2nd to last cards, ensuring they are all
    // of the same suit as the first card in the hand
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (deck[i].suit != deck[0].suit) {
            return 0; // Not a flush
        }
    }

    return 1; // This hand IS a Royal Straight Flush (aka Royal Flush)
}
```

**Final notes:**

- There may be other bugs in this program. For example, `isStraight(...)` skips the first card and loops over the last four cards, but it's ADDING ONE to the index `i` when it should be SUBTRACTING ONE:

  ```
  // Note: This function doesn't recognize a non-sequential "ace-high" flush
  //       (e.g. 10,J,Q,K,A).
  int isStraight(card_t* deck) {
      int i = 0;
      for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
          // Loop values of i will be [1, 2, 3, 4], which correspond to the 2nd through 5th card in the hand passed in.
          // To check these against the previous card, you should subtract one (vs adding one).
          /*
          if (deck[i+1].value != deck[i].value + 1) {  // <--- Array Index Out Of Bounds
          */

          // If card in hand isn't 'one higher' than the previous card...
          if (deck[i-1].value != deck[i].value + 1) {
              return 0;
          }
      }

      return 1;
  }
  ```
- Since you already have a function that checks a hand for flush, you *could* leverage that to save some typing by calling it in your `isRFlush(...)` function:

  ```
  int isRFlush(card_t* deck) {

      if (   deck[0].value != 1       // if 1st card isn't Ace
          || deck[1].value != 10      // or 2nd card isn't 10
          || deck[2].value != 11      // or 3rd card isn't Jack
          || deck[3].value != 12      // or 4th card isn't Queen
          || deck[4].value != 13) {   // or 5th card isn't King

          return 0; // Not a royal straight
      }

      // At this point, you know it's a ROYAL STRAIGHT, so just return whether or not it's also
      // a FLUSH
      return isFlush(deck);
  }
  ```